# Dynamic proxy creation issues with maximum message size

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0

i am creating dyanminc proxy of wcf service without adding a reference to the client code using the MetadataExchenge Class. the problem is when i load metadata of small wcf servcie e.g having only 1 or 2 methods the code works fine for me but as i try to load the metadata of large wcf service having about 70 to 80 methods i get an error of maximum message size 65536 has been exceeded for one of the end points...though i have put all my size variable in wcf config to it's maximum....i dont have anything on my client side web.config file...i am getting all the bindings at run time...can any one help on this??

Comment: You need to set the readerQuotas to large values on the client side. You can also set the readerQuotas programatically.

Comment: How to set that as MetadataExchangeClient class not have publlic property as readersQuota??

Comment: How are you calling your WCFservice from the client? Do you have the binding defined in a config or are your creating an instance of the binding via code

Comment: no i dont have any thing in web config file on client side all are generated at run time i have posted the code BTW

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any thing on client side web.config, because you are trying to consume the web service from code ?

Considering you are using WsHttpBinding for consuming the service, use following code to increase the MaxRecievedMessageSize property.

```
System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.None);

// Increase the message size
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 50000000;

System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient mexClient = new System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient(binding);
System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataSet mexResult = mexClient.GetMetadata(new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://someurl:someport/some"));

foreach (System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataSection section in mexResult.MetadataSections)
{
                Console.WriteLine (section.Identifier);
                Console.WriteLine (section.Metadata.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine ();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

If this does not solve your problem, request you to post your code for further analysis.

Comment: hi anand i have tries this but i got error like "Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://##.##.#.###:8732/WCFTestService/Service1/?wsdl.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched." BTW i am using basicHttpBinding on wcf service config

Comment: Okay, and the example I have given uses WSHttpBinding. Change it to use BasicHttpBinding. It would work then...

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below code in your client side to set the readerQuotas as shown below:

```
            var binding = se.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
            binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize= 2147483647;
            binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
            XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas myReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
            myReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
            myReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
            myReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength= 2147483647;
            myReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead= 2147483647;
            myReaderQuotas.MaxDepth=64;                
            binding.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding, myReaderQuotas, null);
```

The above code needs to be set before you create an instance of proxy.

Answer (score 0):

My code which generate wcf client is as follow

```
 try
            {


            Uri mexAddress = new Uri("http://##.##.#.###:8732/WCFTestService/Service1/?wsdl");
            //MetadataSet metaSet1 = MEC.GetMetadata(new EndpointAddress(mexAddress));
            // For MEX endpoints use a MEX address and a 
            // mexMode of .MetadataExchange
            MetadataExchangeClientMode mexMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.MetadataExchange;

            string contractName = "IVehicleservice";
            string operationName = "ProcessNotification";
            object[] operationParameters = new object[] { 1 };

             //Get the metadata file from the service.
            MetadataExchangeClient mexClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(mexAddress, mexMode);

            mexClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
            mexClient.MaximumResolvedReferences = 100;

            MetadataSet metaSet = mexClient.GetMetadata();


            // Import all contracts and endpoints
            WsdlImporter importer = new WsdlImporter(metaSet);

            Collection<ContractDescription> contracts =
              importer.ImportAllContracts();
            ServiceEndpointCollection allEndpoints = importer.ImportAllEndpoints();

            // Generate type information for each contract
            ServiceContractGenerator generator = new ServiceContractGenerator();
            var endpointsForContracts =
       new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint>>();

            foreach (ContractDescription contract in contracts)
            {
                generator.GenerateServiceContractType(contract);
                // Keep a list of each contract's endpoints
                endpointsForContracts[contract.Name] = allEndpoints.Where(
                    se => se.Contract.Name == contract.Name).ToList();
            }

            if (generator.Errors.Count != 0)
                throw new Exception("There were errors during code compilation.");

            // Generate a code file for the contracts 
            CodeGeneratorOptions options = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
            options.BracingStyle = "C";
            CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");

            // Compile the code file to an in-memory assembly
            // Don't forget to add all WCF-related assemblies as references
            CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(
                new string[] { 
                    "System.dll", "System.ServiceModel.dll", 
                    "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" });
            compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

            CompilerResults results = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(
                compilerParameters, generator.TargetCompileUnit);

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("There were errors during generated code compilation");

            }
            else
            {
                // Find the proxy type that was generated for the specified contract
                // (identified by a class that implements 
                // the contract and ICommunicationbject)
                Type clientProxyType = results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes().First(
                    t => t.IsClass &&
                        t.GetInterface(contractName) != null &&
                        t.GetInterface(typeof(ICommunicationObject).Name) != null);

                // Get the first service endpoint for the contract
                ServiceEndpoint se = endpointsForContracts[contractName].First();

                // Create an instance of the proxy
                // Pass the endpoint's binding and address as parameters
                // to the ctor
                object instance = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(
                   clientProxyType.Name,
                    false,
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance,
                    null,
                    new object[] { se.Binding, se.Address },
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);

                // Get the operation's method, invoke it, and get the return value

                //object retVal = instance.GetType().GetMethod(operationName).
                //    Invoke(instance, operationParameters);

                object retVal = instance.GetType().GetMethod(operationName).
                    Invoke(instance, operationParameters);
                Console.WriteLine(retVal.ToString());

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { 

        }
```

Comment: Do you know what binding is associated with the endpoint on server? Is it basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding or netTcpBinding?

Comment: Assuming you are using BasicHttpBinding from your comments above i posted the code to set readerQuotas programatically